# Why is the chosen:ready-event not triggered?

Tags: jquery, hide, jquery-chosen

I am trying to hide a chosen-control after creation. So I have set some code on `chosen:ready` to hide the container. But it seems that event is not triggered.

**Repro**: [codepen](https://codepen.io/MBaas/pen/pbbENd?editors=1111)

**HTML**:

```
<div style="width:200px;" id="MCchsn_id711552766_2">
    <select id="id711552766_2" style="width:100%" name="id711552766_2">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">[Select]</option>
        <option>ChoiceA</option>
        <option>ChoiceB</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$(function() {
  $("#id711552766_2").chosen();
  $("#id711552766_2").on("update",function () { console.log($(this).text);});
  $("#id711552766_2").on("chosen:ready",function() {$("#MCchsn_id711552766_2").hide();alert("hidden");}); 
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came across this same problem before and figured that you need to bind before instantiating chosen. Try the following:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#id711552766_2").on("change", function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });

  $("#id711552766_2").on("chosen:ready", function() {
    $("#MCchsn_id711552766_2").hide();
    alert("hidden");
  });

  $("#id711552766_2").chosen();

});
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;" id="MCchsn_id711552766_2">
  <select id="id711552766_2" style="width:100%" name="id711552766_2">
                                                            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">[Select]</option>
                              <option>ChoiceA</option>
                              <option>ChoiceB</option>
                                                        </select>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
```

Note: Another thing I noticed in your code was that you were trying to write the selected value. For that to work, you need to change:

```
$(this).text()
```

to

```
$(this).val()
```

Answer (score 3):

your code must be arranged in proper manner.jQuery is Top-Down approach.
[Check Code Here](http://codepen.io/hy5man/pen/NrrdQr)

```
    $(function() {

          $("#id711552766_2").on("chosen:ready" , function() {
               $("#MCchsn_id711552766_2").css('display','none');
               alert("hidden");
          });

          $("#id711552766_2").chosen();$("#id711552766_2").on("update",function() {           
console.log($(this).text);
          });

        });`
```

Comment: Thanks very much :-) I usually accept the first reply, but I found n0m4d's reply to be clearer and he "added value" by addressing the text/val-bug, too.